# Setting custom variables for reinforced learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I apologize in advance this will probably be a long question but ill try and shorten it as i go.

Also a little disclaimer, im really new to machine learning and have only been studying it for about 2 weeks, i understand the basics of neural networks and programing in tensorflow as well as how reinforcement learning works but everything i've learned hasn't helped me enough to work with my situation.

In all the reinforced learning examples i have seen they all use a state and a reward based off of an environment (usually from stuff like vizdoom or openai gym (which being a windows user i cant use the atari or universe without stuff like docker and WSL)) what i've been trying to do is use cv2's get desktop window function to return an array with the pixel value for each pixel in the game window (im trying it on a doom mod thats simple because my pc isnt very powerful) and thats worked out perfectly.

So to get the reward i want to use cv2's matchtemplate function to check if the game screen matches the win screen and reward if it is or if the screen matches the lose screen then punish also for the state i want to just use the output from my cv2 getdesktopwindow function for my DRQN Network (which also works perfectly with openai's gym cartpole and such using the open ai env tools) but i cant figure out how to do it with doom and cv2.

I left out ALOT of stuff to keep it simple, also i have deleted most of my code that didn't work but i still have old stuff if it would help, so yeah just ask if you need it. Any help at all, even just links to some resources that explain how to set custom variables for a RL algorithm would be much apreciated because i can only find stuff for things like openai gym and such, thanks. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but [`tf.get_variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable) lets you create/get a new variable in TensorFlow.